# Add command to visudo with dynamic parameters

Tags: perl, visudo

I've writen a perl script that needs sudo rights, but it accepts parameters that are always different. eg

```
sudo /home/user/script.pl user
```

I guess adding this to visudo will not work. Is this possible?
If not I was thinking about maybe using something like a pipe to solve this problemm like:

```
echo user | sudo /home/user/script.pl
```

Is there a way to pass variables this way to a perl script?

The only other option I see is writing the parameters to a file. Then I can still add the script to visudo.

Comment: Just adding `/home/user/script.pl` as the command will allow calling it with any arguments.

Comment: @Grinnz Thanks. I didn't know that. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use **ARGV**?
content of *tmp/script.pl*

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print join(',', @ARGV);

exit;
```

and as result

```
$ sudo perl tmp/script.pl foo bar
> foo,bar
```

Or you can use **Getopt::Long** (extended processing of command line options)